# How can I use a text as a button in Corona SDK?

Tags: button, text, coronasdk

Hello I am new in Corona SDK and I want to help me with my problem: Is it possible to use a text as button in Corona, and if yes can you show me how to do it? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each object in Corona can be assigned an event listener, which will respond to whatever event your subscribe it to. For a text to act as a button, you can do the following:

1. Create text object

   ```
   local txtObj = display.newText('some text', 50, 50, native.systemFont, 20)
   ```
2. Create a method that will be executed upon text touch, eg.:

   ```
   local function onClick(event)
       print('I've been clicked')
   end
   ```
3. Add event listener to your text object

   ```
   txtObj:addEventListener('touch', onClick)
   ```

Now touching your text object will call **onClick** method, hence you're text will act like a button.

This is the simplest example, and there is much more to learn about events. See great documentation [here](http://docs.coronalabs.com/daily/guide/events/detectEvents/index.html) and [here](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/event/touch/phase.html).

Answer (score 0):

This is what widget.newButton() can do for you.